# What has happened to my dwellers armour when I sent him to the wasteland?

Tags: fallout-shelter

When I sent my dweller to the wasteland he was wearing raider armour. When I looked at him to see how he was going he was wearing hardened leather armour and I couldn’t see any raider armour in my storage. Why has this happened?

Answer (score 7):

They will have it in their loot.

When exploring if they find better weapons or armour they will switch automatically.